# Logitech Trackman "letting go"

Tags: windows, mouse, hardware-failure

Wondering if anyone's seen this issue where you're clicking and holding with a Logitech trackball and, although you're still holding the primary mouse button the OS (Windows in my case) acts as if you've released it.

It's quite inconvenient, particularly if you're trying to lasso select some files and drag and drop them etc.

I've seen [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/339587/logitech-m705-left-mouse-button-doesnt-stay-down-when-pressed) and, while it may share some common components, it's neither the same mouse nor OS. Also given that the device in question is [still under warranty](http://support.logitech.com/en_roeu/product/wireless-trackball-m570#warranty) I'd be loath to invalidate it by opening the device up.

The trackball is a M570, about 2.5 years old so it's possible that it's a function of age but I'd like to know definitively before I purchase a new/alternative model.

If I use Spy++ to monitor window messages then I can clearly see that's there's a series of mouse down/mouse up/mouse down messages like this:

```
<000001> 0001014E P WM_LBUTTONDOWN fwKeys:MK_LBUTTON xPos:1561 yPos:5
<000002> 0001014E P WM_LBUTTONUP fwKeys:0000 xPos:1394 yPos:801
<000003> 0001014E P WM_LBUTTONDOWN fwKeys:MK_LBUTTON xPos:1593 yPos:0
<000004> 0001014E P WM_LBUTTONUP fwKeys:0000 xPos:1593 yPos:0
```

Basically the button leaves go for a split second and then re-engages again. Smells like a hardware fault alright.

Comment: I concur with Karan, I have also experienced the "letting go" on a completely different brand of mouse (Microsoft Comfort Optical 3000) and it was definitely the mouse not continuing the button press signal as long as I had it pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Logitech M570 is an excellent pointing device, but there seem to be inconsistencies in the production and some quality control issues.

If the button is releasing without you releasing it, that is a hardware issue (the button switch inside is most likely not working to spec).  Your best recourse is to contact Logitech and see if they are willing to help you.  Please comment below with your experience as to their helpfulness and willingness to fix the problem.

If you buy a new Logitech M570, note that it will feel very different than your older one.  That's expected.  It has a break-in period of several days before the ball will start moving freely.  Furthermore, the wheel typically takes about a week to start feeling smooth.